# How to access JSON data in AJAX method?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

How do access data I have encoded from a PHP to in a `$ajax()` method?

My question mainly is what to use as a variable and what should be the value of the data attribute? Here is the code that I have so far. I am new to AJAX and I would appreciate an answer, thanks in advance.

```
$dcweather = array('weather' => "$DCfahrenheit", 'wind' => "$DCwind", 'humidity' => "$DChumidity");
$jsonCode = json_encode($dcweather);
echo ($jsonCode);
```

```js
('#button_dc').click(function() {
  var data = {
    weather: "$DCfahrenheit",
    wind: "DCwind",
    humidity: "DChumidity"
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'DCweather.php',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      consol.log(result);
      $('#div_new').replaceWith(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Firstly note that `consol.log` needs to be `console.log` and you're missing a `$` on the first jQuery object. Secondly, the `result` variable will be an object which holds the properties and values you send back from `$jsonCode` in the PHP, as such you can access it as you normally would, ie. `result.weather // == '$DCfahrenheit'`

Comment: I'm confused what the goal is. What are you trying to do? From what you're showing, the post data does nothing, and you get strings back (unless each of the variables are defined somewhere).

Comment: @kchason I am trying to get the weather, humidity, and wind and show it when the button is clicked. And I am not sure what to put in the data attribute in order to do that.

Comment: Right, so I assume `$DCFahrenheit` etc are already defined? Does your script depend on any variables, such as location or date? If not, and it only does DC for the current day, then you don't need any parameters for `data`. It just posts it so it is accessible in the `$_POST` array for the `DCWeather.php` script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the code above `result` would be a object with the indices of weather, wind, and humidity.

So:

`result.weather` would be whatever $DCfahrenheit was set to on the server.

However, the typo of `consol.log(result)` with throw an error, and no further code will be processed.

Answer (score -1):

If you are returning multiple values in one object, its better to then specifically place each returned piece of data into a specific html element in your success function.